# Ruby File.absolute_path returning unexpected values

Tags: ruby, irb

I'm running a test script where one ruby script reads and executes additional ruby scripts from a 'scripts' folder.

```
Folder structure:
RubyInception
  |_main.rb
  |_scripts
     |_1.rb
     |_2.rb
```

Testing the filepaths like so:

```
irb(main):014:0> Dir.foreach('./scripts') {|x| puts File.absolute_path x}
```

yielded the following results:

```
C:/.../Desktop/RubyInception
C:/.../Desktop
C:/.../Desktop/RubyInception/1.rb
C:/.../Desktop/RubyInception/2.rb
```

Why isn't it showing:

```
C:/.../Desktop/RubyInception/scripts/1.rb
```

?

Environment:

Windows 7 Prof x64

ruby 1.9.3p448

SOLUTION:
What worked for me:

```
Dir["./scripts/*.rb"].each {|x| puts File.absolute_path x }
```

Comment: If I do a Dir.chdir('./scripts') before executing this line, then I get the expected values, but why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From documentation of [`Dir.foreach`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/Dir.html#method-c-foreach)

> Calls the block once for each entry in the named directory, ***passing the filename*** of each entry as a parameter to the block.

When you call

```
Dir.foreach('./scripts')
```

it yields the following sequence to your block

```
.
..
1.rb
2.rb
```

Note that no path information is contained in the result. Then in your block, you tried to resolve the absolute path of each filename. Since the filename doesn't have absolute path prefixed, the current working directory (`CWD`, or `PWD`) is used to resolve the absolute path of each entry. When `CWD` is `RubyInception`, you get:

```
File.absolute_path('.')          => C:/.../Desktop/RubyInception
File.absolute_path('..')         => C:/.../Desktop
File.absolute_path('1.rb')       => C:/.../Desktop/RubyInception/1.rb
File.absolute_path('2.rb')       => C:/.../Desktop/RubyInception/2.rb
```

When `CWD` is `scripts`, you get:

```
File.absolute_path('.')          => C:/.../Desktop/RubyInception/scripts
File.absolute_path('..')         => C:/.../Desktop/RubyInception
File.absolute_path('1.rb')       => C:/.../Desktop/RubyInception/scripts/1.rb
File.absolute_path('2.rb')       => C:/.../Desktop/RubyInception/scripts/2.rb
```

In summary, when you work with the file API of any programming language (is there any exception?), keep in mind the relative path starts from current working directory.

Answer (score 0):

See the [documentation](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/File.html#method-c-absolute_path) for explanation:

> Relative paths are referenced from the current working directory of
>   the process unless dir_string is given, in which case it will be used
>   as the starting point.

So you could either use the `dir_string` parameter:

```
Dir.foreach('./scripts') {|x| puts File.absolute_path x, 'scripts'}
```

Or [`Dir.glob`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Dir.html#method-c-glob):

```
Dir.glob('./scripts/*.rb') {|x| puts File.absolute_path x}
```

Comment: The documentation is nonsensical--as is the result.  Any method that produces an "absolute path" that doesn't exist is a bit puzzling.

Comment: @7stud You shouldn't downvote my answer just because you don't like the way Ruby works. `Dir.foreach` returns `1.rb`, `Dir.glob` returns `./scripts/1.rb`. Ruby has only these strings and the path to the current directory. This is the reason it can construct the absolute path correctly for `Dir.glob`, but not for `Dir.foreach`.

Comment: `You shouldn't downvote my answer just because you don't like the way Ruby works`  That's not why I downvoted your answer.  I downvoted your answer because you referenced nonsensical docs as the reason for the output the op is seeing.  If you erase that nonsense and add your sensible comment to your answer, I will reverse my downvote...and I could even upvote your post.

Comment: @7stud What is nonsensical in the documentation? "Relative paths (`1.rb`) are referenced from the current working directory (`C:/.../Desktop/RubyInception/`)". The concatenation of these two strings is the wrong path (`C:/.../Desktop/RubyInception/1.rb`).